# TypeError in "path" when running Firebase Functions Test

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm writing a test for a google cloud function which'll write some information to a firestore database. The test uses `firebase-functions-test` and jest. The function I'm writing works successfully when I deploy it but when I try to run the test I get:

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type object

      at GrpcClient.loadProto (node_modules/google-gax/src/grpc.ts:182:23)
      at new FirestoreClient (node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/v1/firestore_client.js:113:32)
      at ClientPool.Firestore._clientPool.pool_1.ClientPool [as clientFactory] (node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/index.js:319:26)
      at ClientPool.acquire (node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/pool.js:81:35)
      at ClientPool.run (node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/pool.js:155:29)
      at Firestore.request (node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/index.js:885:33)
      at WriteBatch.commit_ (node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/write-batch.js:450:14)
```

My function:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const db = admin.firestore();

const saveCheckup = functions.pubsub.topic('save-test').onPublish((message) => {
  const {url, ...dataToSave} = message.attributes;

  let current = db.collection('current').doc(url);
  current.set(dataToSave, {merge: true})

  return true;
});

module.exports = saveCheckup;
```

My test:

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

const testEnv = require('firebase-functions-test')(
  {
    databaseURL: "https://my-project.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: 'my-project',
    storageBucket: 'my-project.appspot.com'
  }, "./my-project-firebase-adminsdk.json"
);


describe('saveCheckup', () => {
  let adminStub, saveCheckup;

  beforeAll(() => {
    adminStub = jest.spyOn(admin, "initializeApp");
    saveCheckup = require('../functions/save_checkup');
  });

  afterAll(() => {
    adminStub.mockRestore();
    testEnv.cleanup();
    admin.database().ref("current").remove();
  });

  it("should save the user", async () => {
    const wrapped = testEnv.wrap(saveCheckup);

    await wrapped({attributes: {
      date: "test date",
      url: "testurl",
      status: "200"
    }});

    const record = await admin.database().ref('/current/testurl').once('value');
    expect(record.val()).toHaveProperty("status", "200");
  })
});
```

Update: We were not able to solve this problem and ended up just writing offline tests for firestore instead.

Comment: Your code seems incomplete or incorrect.  Please edit the question to be clear what `docUrl` is, as there is no definition for that variable.  Did you mean `doc`?  What is its value?

Comment: docUrl is url, which is one of the attributes we receive in message. I've updated the code to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

The error output you posted shows that the error is within the Google Firebase node module files. 
It even shows the line and character location:

```
at new FirestoreClient (node_modules/.../v1/firestore_client.js:113:32)
//                                             Error location here ^
```

If you are trying to deploy locally please read this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/deploying
and follow the directions according to your situation.

Comment: I'm not trying to deploy locally, I'm trying to write a test using firebase-functions-test. 

The error in firestore_client which it calls out is `const protos = gaxGrpc.loadProto(opts.fallback ? require('../../protos/protos.json') : nodejsProtoPath);`

Comment: I wasn't necessarily meaning deploy locally, but more as test locally then deploy.

Answer (score 0):

Add a "jest.config.js" into the root directory keep the following code into the file

```
module.exports = {
    testPathIgnorePatterns: ['lib/', 'node_modules/'],
    moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'jsx', 'json', 'node'],
    testEnvironment: 'node'
};
```